# How to make readline work inside a loop in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am really a newbie on Typescript. I wrote a piece of code to do something like C's "While + scanf".

Here below is my code:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
let more = 1;
while (more) {
    rl.question("Do you want more ", function(answer) {
        if (answer == "no") {
           more = 0;
           console.log("bye");
        } else {
            more++;
            console.log("next round.." + more);
        }
        rl.close();
    });
}
```

To my surprise, before I can type anything, my console was flooded with "Do you want more". I googled around and suspected something related to asynchronous. But I still don't know how to properly make this simple piece of code to work.

Comment: `rl.question` doesn't block the execution. So, `while` will just execute the question more and more, instead of waiting for an answer. This is not the correct tool in this case - you don't need a loop here  and you need to only stop listening for input on `"no"`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your response. So how can I "block" the while loop? Is it possible for Typescript?

Comment: No, you cannot "block" the loop. Not in the general case. It's simply a very bad practice - the normal way would not involve a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to

```js
import * as readline from 'readline';
import * as process from 'process';
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
let more = 1;
read();

function read() {
    rl.question("Do you want more ", function (answer) {
        if (answer == "no") {
            more = 0;
            console.log("bye");
            rl.close();
        } else {
            more++;
            console.log("next round.." + more);
            read();
        }
    });
}
```

Use readline-sync

```js
import * as rl from 'readline-sync';
var more = 1;
read();
function read() {
    while (more) {
        let answer = rl.question("Do you want more ");
        if (answer == "no") {
            more = 0;
            console.log("bye");
        } else {
            more++;
            console.log("next round.." + more);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Phat Huynh, thanks for you reply. Since I am studying this language. Is it possible to achieve the same result by looping like 'while' or 'for' ?

Comment: It's depended to readline package, if you want use for or while like other language, use readline-sync package

Comment: Thanks@Phat Huynh. it seems I need more knowledeg of sync. Any book recommanded?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: why the first recursive example won't print "Do you want more" many times? Since it basicly calls the read() continuaslly..

Comment: rl.question(message, callback);  about callback: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced